# How to download Data file with php link (Dynamic url) and login with wget

Tags: command-line, php, wget

While downloading from a link from Human 3.6 M database I received following error.

```
user@ubuntu:/disk1/user/Human_3.6m_data$ bash download0.sh
user@ubuntu:/disk1/user/Human_3.6m_data$ --2017-12-18 23:52:10--  http://vision.imar.ro/human3.6m/filebrowser.php?download=1
Connecting to [ip address]... connected.
Proxy request sent, awaiting response... 302 Found
Location: main_login.php [following]
--2017-12-18 23:52:11--  http://vision.imar.ro/human3.6m/main_login.php
Reusing existing connection to [ip address].
Proxy request sent, awaiting response... 302 Found
Location: https://vision.imar.ro/human3.6m/main_login.php [following]
--2017-12-18 23:52:11--  https://vision.imar.ro/human3.6m/main_login.php
Connecting to [ip address]... connected.
WARNING: cannot verify vision.imar.ro's certificate, issued by ‘emailAddress=root@vision,CN=vision,OU=SomeOrganizationalUnit,O=SomeOrganization,L=SomeCity,ST=SomeState,C=--’:
   Self-signed certificate encountered.
     WARNING: certificate common name ‘vision’ doesn't match requested host name ‘vision.imar.ro’.
Proxy request sent, awaiting response... 200 OK
Length: 2600 (2.5K) [text/html]
Saving to: ‘filebrowser.php?download=1.1’

filebrowser.php?download=1.1                    100%[====================================================================================================>]   2.54K  --.-KB/s    in 0s

2017-12-18 23:52:13 (74.0 MB/s) - ‘filebrowser.php?download=1.1’ saved [2600/2600]
```

Link for download is

> http://vision.imar.ro/human3.6m/filebrowser.php?download=1&filepath=Videos&filename=ActivitySpecific_1.tgz&downloadname=Directions

I used these linux commands:

> wget --no-check-certificate --user usr --password pswd http://vision.imar.ro/human3.6m/filebrowser.php?download=1&filepath=Videos&filename=ActivitySpecific_1.tgz&downloadname=Directions
>
> wget --no-check-certificate --trust-server-names --user usr --password pswd  -O Directions http://vision.imar.ro/human3.6m/filebrowser.php?download=1&filepath=Videos&filename=ActivitySpecific_1.tgz&downloadname=Directions

Actual Data is 6 GB in size.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First you *must* quote the URL:

```
wget --no-check-certificate --user usr --password pswd \
'http://vision.imar.ro/human3.6m/filebrowser.php?download=1&filepath=Videos&filename=ActivitySpecific_1.tgz&downloadname=Directions'
```

Otherwise everything after the first `&` is cut off by the shell, and you would also see this:

```
[1] 20618
[2] 20619
[1]-  Done                    filepath=Videos
$ 
[2]+  Done                    filename=ActivitySpecific_1.tgz
```

Second, the small file was probably this.

[image]

Those `--user` and `--password` options won't usually work.  For cookie based logins, you need to do something like this (Adapted from info at `man wget`, `/`, `--post`):

```
wget --no-check-certificate --keep-session-cookies --save-cookies cookies.txt \
--post-data 'username=foo&password=bar' \
'https://vision.imar.ro/human3.6m/checklogin.php'

# Now grab the page or pages we care about.
wget --no-check-certificate --load-cookies cookies.txt \
'https://vision.imar.ro/human3.6m/filebrowser.php?download=1&filepath=Videos&filename=ActivitySpecific_1.tgz&downloadname=Directions'
```

Comment: Thank You. Working like a Charm now. Will remember this.